# How can I start redis on RedHat RHEL 6?

Tags: redhat, redis

I followed the instructions for installing `redis` from [here](http://vincentvandaal.nl/271/redis-quick-install-on-redhat-based-distro/).

I also ran:

```
make test
```

and all the tests passed. Then:

```
make install
```

and that appears to have worked. I've done all this as `root`.

But install really appears to have done very little if anything. I can't start redis as a service with:

```
start redis.service
```

which gives:

```
start: Unknown job: redis.service
```

and there are no redis directories under `/etc/init.d`. There must be some simple command I can run.

The executables have been correctly placed in `/usr/local`. If I run `redis-server`, it definitely runs, but quits when I `Ctrl-C`. Do I just need to run this with `nohup`? I want redis to run upon startup and this seems unreliable.

Comment: Try following the directions given in the tutorial instead.

Comment: I missed a step. The internet has ruined my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other way's of doing this, but not being familiar with redis and its specific limitations: one easy option would be to add your launch line to

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Anything listed there will run on boot.